# How can I change FTP port in Coda?

Tags: ftp, coda

I changed the FTP port on my server (not for security, but for access from Panera Bread which blocks port 21 :) ) and I can access it just fine using FTP clients such as Firebird.

But when I try change the port in Panic's Coda, the port appears to be saved but I always get an 'illegal port' error when I try to connect. This is the same with port 2121 or port 23 or anything I try. Does anyone know how to fix this? it is difficult to tell whether it is a Coda bug or now and getting a response from Coda is impossible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is a bug in Coda and is being worked on by them. You can connect directly, but if you try to set up a project, it will fail on any port other than 21.